# Different lucene search results using different search space size

Tags: java, search, lucene, size, scoring

I have an application that uses lucene for searching. The search space are in the thousands. Searching against these thousands, I get only a few results, around 20 (which is ok and expected).

However, when I reduce my search space to just those 20 entries (i.e. I indexed only those 20 entries and disregard everything else...so that development would be easier), I get the same 20 results but in different order (and scoring).

I tried disabling the norm factors via Field#setOmitNorms(true), but I still get different results?

What could be causing the difference in the scoring?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please see the scoring documentation in Lucene's [Similarity API](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_9_1/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/Similarity.html). My bet is on the difference in idf between the two cases (both numDocs and docFreq are different). In order to know for sure, use the [explain()](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_9_1/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/Searcher.html#explain%28org.apache.lucene.search.Query,%20int%29) function to debug the scores.

Edit: A code fragment for getting explanations:

```
TopDocs hits = searcher.search(query, searchFilter, max);
ScoreDoc[] scoreDocs = hits.scoreDocs;
for (ScoreDoc scoreDoc : scoreDocs) {
  String explanation = searcher.explain(query, scoreDoc.doc).toString();
  Log.debug(explanation);
}
```

Comment: Pardon, but where can I get the int (second parameter) of explain() ?

Comment: I didn't had much time to go back at my problem but this suggestion seems to point to the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Scoring depends on all the documents in the index:

> In general, the idea behind the
>   Vector Space Model (VSM) is the more
>   times a query term appears in a
>   document relative to the number of
>   times the term appears in all the
>   documents in the collection, the more relevant that document is to the query.

Source: [Apache Lucene - Scoring](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/scoring.html)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that. So if I searched for a person given the name 'Mark' against all the person in my search space, I'll be getting 'Mark Anthony', 'Markos', and 'Mark'. But if I limit the search space to those 3 only (just limit the indexing to just those 3), I will get 'Mark', 'Mark Anthony', and 'Markos'. How come their sorting will change given the same relevant documents but different 'noise' documents?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an expert either. Did you have a look at http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/api/org/apache/lucene/search/Similarity.html ?