# BooleanQuery Too Many Clauses in Lucene

Tags: java, lucene

For a bit of background to know what i am doing:

[using hit highlighter in lucene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409870/using-hit-highlighter-in-lucene)

Now to solve this problem i am setting maxclause count to 50000.

it works.

can there be any problems by increasing the number of clauses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have too many clauses, performance will suffer, especially if you are running disjunctive (OR) queries.  In some rare cases, you might run out of memory.