# Get stemmed word in Lucene

Tags: lucene, snowballanalyzer

In Lucene I use the SnowballAnalyzer for indexing and searching.

When I have the index built I make queries on my index. For example I make a query 'specialized' for the field 'body'.
IndexSearcher returns documents containing 'specialize, specialized etc.' because of the stemming done by the SnowballAnalyzer.

Now - having top documents - I want to get a text snippet from the body field. This snipped should contain the stemmed version of the query word.
For example one of the returned documents has the body field: "Unfortunately, in some states, blind people only have access to general rehabilitation agencies, which serve people with a variety of disabilities. In these cases, specialized services for visually impaired people are not always available." 
Then I wish to get the part 'In these cases, specialized services for visually' as the snippet.
Additionally I want to have terms from this snippet. Code which will do it, but with one marked '?' character, where I have a question is:

How I want to do it is
`IndexReader ir = IndexReader.open(fsDir);

                TermPositionVector tv =   (TermPositionVector)ir.getTermFreqVector(hits.scoreDocs[i].doc, "body");`

? - here: query - query has to be the term. So if the real query
was 'specialized' then the query should be specialize, what normally the snowball analyzer does.  How can I get the term analyzed by the analyzer for a single word or a phrase, since query can contain a phrase: "specialized machines".

`int idx = tv.indexOf(query);

                int [] idxs = tv.getTermPositions(idx);

                for(String t : tv.getTerms()){

                    int iidx = tv.indexOf(t);

                    int [] iidxs = tv.getTermPositions(iidx);

                    for(int ni : idxs){

                        tmpValue = 0.0f;

                        for(int nni : iidxs){

                            if(Math.abs(nni-ni)<= Settings.termWindowSize){`

**edit**
I found the way to get the stemmed term:
    
    `Query q = queryParser.parse("some text to be parsed");
    String parsedQuery = q.toString();`

There is a method for the Query object [toString(String fieldName)](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_2/api/core/index.html?org/apache/lucene/search/TopFieldDocs.html);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are mixing several questions.
First, to see the stemmed version of your query, and other useful information, you can use the IndexSearcher's explain() method. Please see [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409870/using-hit-highlighter-in-lucene).

The Lucene solution for getting snippets is the [Highlighter](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_2/api/contrib-highlighter/org/apache/lucene/search/highlight/Highlighter.html). Another option is the [FastVectorHighlighter](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_2/api/contrib-fast-vector-highlighter/org/apache/lucene/search/vectorhighlight/FastVectorHighlighter.html). I believe you can customize both to get the stemmed term rather than the full one.

Comment: Thx for your reply. Please see my post update to see a way to get the stemmed term.