# Custom highlighter with lucene

Tags: lucene

By default the lucene highlighter highlights the search string using bold tags. Can I provide my own highlighting scheme, using some other color for highlighting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using just the regular `Highlighter`, you can pass it the `SimpleHTMLFormatter` constructed with whatever pre and post tags you want:

```
new Highlighter(fragmentScorer, new SimpleHTMLFormatter("<span>", "</span>"));
```

Of course, there are other formatters, like the `GradientFormatter`, that will highlight the term with based on a minimum and maximum color determined by score, all which you can set via the constructor.  The `SpanGradientFormatter` does something similar, as well.

Comment: Can you or @gotuskar add a sample code snippet on how to use the Highlighter please..

Comment: @Anand I don't have that piece of code now. Take a look at these examples http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409870/using-hit-highlighter-in-lucene, http://hrycan.com/2009/10/25/lucene-highlighter-howto/

Comment: Thanks for pointing to that example, [HERE](http://db.tt/RdW3EhXT) is a simple working copy/demo/helloworld app.